# Navigate ListView with Keyboard without selecting (UWP)

Tags: listview, uwp, focus, uwp-xaml, listviewitem

I noticed that when navigating a *ListView* with the arrow keys, it will mark the *ListItem* as selected (though not trigger any click). However, if I also keep Ctrl+Shift pressed, then the focus moves without selecting the items. Is there a way to make that the default? Or even better, to make the state match the one of *PointerOver*? I have different background colors for selected and pointer over states and would like the mouse behaviour to match the keyboard's.

Answer (score 0):

This action is specific to Listview's `SelectionMode` property. As per this document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.selectionmode#remarks)

**Single**

1. *With no modifier keys:* A user can select a single item using the space bar, mouse click, or touch tap. A user can deselect an item
   using a downward swipe gesture.
2. *While pressing Ctrl:* Using the arrow keys, a user can move focus independently of selection.

**Multiple**

1. *With no modifier keys:* A user can select multiple items using the space bar, mouse click, or touch tap to toggle selection on the
   focused item. Using the arrow keys, **a user can move focus
   independently of selection**.

If you need to change this default behavior you can use `PreviewKeyDown` event for listview.

//Code Sample

```
private void ListView_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Key == VirtualKey.Down)
  {
    FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Down);
    e.Handled = true;
  }
  else if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Up)
  {
    FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Up);
    e.Handled = true;
  }
  else
  {
    e.Handled = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While Vignesh's solution works for the common cases, it doesn't work for certain other cases. For e.g. when pressing PageDown using a Keyboard on a long list, the item still gets selected instead of only changing focus.

If your app is targeting Windows 10 Version 1607 (Anniversary Update) or greater, then the only solution that worked for me was using the [SingleSelectionFollowsFocus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.singleselectionfollowsfocus?view=winrt-19041) property on the ListView. Set this to False with [SelectionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.selectionmode?view=winrt-19041) set to Single.